# Cocoa = How to run script in background without launching terminal in C

Tags: linux, macos, cocoa, terminal, applescript

In my Cocoa Application, I am running a script by using c functions like `setenv()` and `popen()`. It executes the script perfectly. But the issue is, At runtime, `popen()` opens the Terminal app and after the script is executed, It closes the Terminal app automatically. I want to execute the script without opening the Terminal app.

I found a solution to use `NSAppleScript`. But This class is available only in Foundation, but not available in Core Foundation. I want the same feature to be written in C. How to achieve this.

Please advice.

Comment: You need to show your code, or people will just be guessing trying to help you. Edit the question to add it, then someone might offer you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`NSTask`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nstask) to execute the script. This allows you to have it run in background while still being able to specify environment variables, monitor output, etc.